# Logs for Rasa in command-line mode

Tags: logging, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I would like to log conversation (especially intents) from a Rasa bot. There is a perfect feature for that when Rasa NLU is run as an http server, but I can't seem to find anything similar when running in command-line mode. Is there a way to do that ? If, not, would there be a way to implement that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rasa Core [architecture](https://core.rasa.com/plumbing.html) a class called Tracker contains the history of the current conversation.
I imagine you may implement your log by calling its `as_dialogue` [method](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/241979ca4fbe22083aec7b1b6c37810cc0ce2e6c/rasa_core/trackers.py#L281).

Looking at the [docs](https://core.rasa.com/state.html#serialisation), the output of this serialization seems to be exactly like the items in the logs produced by the server:

```
{  
  "py/object":"rasa_core.conversation.Dialogue",
  "events":[
    {
      "py/object": "rasa_core.events.UserUttered",
      "entities": [],
      "intent": {
        "name": "greet",
        "confidence": 1.0
      },
      "text": "/greet"
    },
    {
      "py/object": "rasa_core.events.ActionExecuted",
      "action_name": "utter_greet",
      "unpredictable": false
    }
  ],
  "name":"hello_world"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean exactly by command line mode? If you start the server with:

```
python -m rasa_nlu.server --path projects --response_log logs
```

logging should be enabled. This assumes version 0.12.3

Comment: I mean by not starting nlu as a server at all, but using cmd-line input/output to ineract with it  
This is the code for launching the bot:  

`def run(serve_forever=True):  
    interpreter = RasaNLUInterpreter("models/nlu/default/current")  
    agent = Agent.load("models/dialogue", interpreter=interpreter)  

    if serve_forever:  
        agent.handle_channel(ConsoleInputChannel())  
    return agent`